# Given the geo location from the GPS, how to find the latitude and longitude within a given x meter radius

Tags: java, android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I was writing an android app and I was wondering if there is any API that helps to plugin a latitude and longitude obtained from the GPS and also plugin a radius R, find the new latitude and longitude with a very high precision. Preferably a Java code. 
So say for example the current location is curX and curY
now within 200 meter radius of this location can be maxX and maxY. So if I have a list of entries, I will print only the entries within the max Range. So for comparison to be right, the precision should  be high. Is there any API that can do this? Any formula? (in Java)

```
So the function is
findNewLatitude(curLat,curLong,oldList,radius)
{
  do bla bla bla; //Find a newList with respect to current Geo points on MAP  and      considering the radius
}

output: newList such that distance between (lat,long) in newList and 
(curLat,curLong) is  equal to radius
```

Comment: Is this what you want? Among a given Set S of locations find those locations L within a radius R of a given location CURRENT, and among L find the location with the greatest distance to CURRENT.

Comment: @Stefan Your rephrasing is partially right. As in, find L within a Radius R of given location CURRENT. This much is my main objective.

Comment: Ok, then the answer from Gabriel Negut (see below) solves your problem, I guess.

Comment: See my answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21100/6020

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Location> filter(Location current, List<Location> locations, int radius) {
    List<Location> results = new ArrayList<Location>();
    for (Location loc : locations) {
        if (current.distanceTo(loc) <= radius) {
            results.add(loc);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```